# How can I get repository resources associated with the given build in Azure DevOps using REST Api?

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-server-2020

Please, observe the following image:
[image]

It shows a Pull Request Build summary page. There we can see the build has two repository resources. This is because the build checks out multiple repositories. The first one is self, the other one is auxiliary.

I am trying to figure out what REST API I can use to get the information about the auxiliary repository associated with the given build. This is one of the rare cases when using the network capture proved useless to deduce the right API.

I tried the Pipeline Run API - `http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/{OurProject}/_apis/pipelines/{BuildDefinitionID}/runs/{BuildID}?api-version=6.0-preview.1` - it does not return what I need.

So how do we do it?

(The build is a YAML build)

We use Azure DevOps Server 2020 on-prem.

Comment: What version of Azure DevOps Server are you using?

Comment: 2020. Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure DevOps API to access Multi Repo Sources of a Build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63569563/azure-devops-api-to-access-multi-repo-sources-of-a-build)

Comment: @AJHenderson - looks like it.