# How do you get the version for a the source repos for a given build?

Tags: azure-devops

I have a pipeline that has

```
resources:
  repositories:
```

In the GUI I can get the commit hash at the time the pipeline is run

[image]

How would I get that through CLI (or REST API if not possible on CLI)

From the console, it appears to get it using a /Contribution/HierarchyQuery

Comment: You can use the pipeline resource metadata as predefined variables $(resources.pipeline.<Alias>.sourceCommit) for resources. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/resources-pipelines-pipeline?view=azure-pipelines#the-pipeline-resource-metadata-as-predefined-variables. In general predefined variables are quite powerful - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Comment: @evgeny the `resources.pipeline.<Alias>.sourceCommit` will be from the same repo at the pipeline resource being referenced.. not usually what you want if you are building from multiple repos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the rest api which is not document:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{Organization}/{Project}/_build/results?buildId={Build ID}&__rt=fps&__ver=2
```

Its response body is quite massive, the information about multiple repositories is in:

`fps -> dataProviders -> data -> ms.vss-build-web.run-details-data-provider -> repositoryResources`.

Please check the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63571353/14996050) for the details.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will work, but I would try to cd into the repository directory for example `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/repo` and then I would perform a powershell task

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: get git hash ID
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      (git log --format="%H" -n 1).substring(0,8)
```

Comment: I'm trying to get it through the CLI since these are "older" builds.