# how to read last commit hash of other repository in multi stage

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have set-up like below.

```
resources:
repos:
  repoA:
  repoB:

Stage a: checkout A (so will get commit hash from BUILD_SOURCEVERSION variable)
```

I want to read the commit hash from repoB, how can we read other repo commit hash here to variable?

Comment: Does this help? I answered the same question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71879364/how-do-you-get-the-version-for-a-the-source-repos-for-a-given-build/71881457#71881457 cd into directory and run a powershell task. .

Comment: The previous comment is partially correct, you need to cd into the repository directory and then you just run this `git rev-parse HEAD`

Answer (score 0):

Here below an example of how to do it.
You can just leverage git to get the hash, but as GeralexGR mentioned you will need to cd into the repo folder first.

```
jobs:
- job: test
  steps:
    - checkout: REPOA
    - checkout: REPOB
    - bash: |
        cd $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/REPOA
        TAG_HASHA=$(git rev-parse HEAD)
        echo $TAG_HASHA
        cd $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/REPOB
        TAG_HASHB=$(git rev-parse HEAD)
        echo $TAG_HASHB
      displayName: 'pickHash'
```