# How can I distinguish builds from different branches?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am using the MS Azure DevOps REST API to download artifacts from the latest pipeline build from a given branch.

To do so, I first need to find out the build definition ID, which I do using the [`definitions` GET endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1) (and then filtering the result by the pipeline name).

Once I have this, I can use the [`builds` GET endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1) to fetch the latest successful builds for my build definition ID.

Now, my problem is this - the underlying pipeline is executed for different branches in my source repository. In the web-based DevOps UI, that looks like this for a given pipeline run:

[image: pipeline run sources]

In there, the first source repository/branch is the one where the pipeline YAML is hosted. That's always the same.

The second one is the one I'm actually interested in; it indicates which release branch the build was executed from.

Unfortunately, I cannot find this information in the [`Build` data structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1#build) as returned from the `builds` endpoint; at least not in an intuitively typed and named field. There are two properties named `repository` and `sourceBranch`, but they only contain information about the *first* listed repo/branch from the DevOps web interface.

**How can I distinguish builds from my different release branches when retrieving information via the public Azure DevOps REST API?**

Comment: Does [Azure DevOps API to access Multi Repo Sources of a Build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63569563/azure-devops-api-to-access-multi-repo-sources-of-a-build) help? The answer describes an undocumented API. See also [How to get source repositories of a build through Azure DevOps REST APIs](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/how-to-get-source-repositories-of-a-build-through/1246793).

Comment: @JonathanDodds: Not really; that API doesn't appear to be just undocumented, it's not even under the `_apis` route. As such, I'm not convinced it actually comes with any guarantees of remaining stable without breaking changes. Given that it looks kind of like the URL to the DevOps web interface, calling that API feels a lot like scraping the DevOps HTML page and just hoping the result remains more or less consistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I distinguish builds from my different release branches when retrieving information via the public Azure DevOps REST API?

You can use the Rest API: [Runs - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1) to get the Pipeline resource repo branch info.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/{pipelineId}/runs/{runId}?api-version=7.1-preview.1
```

For example:

```
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: common
      type: git
      ref: main
      name: pipelines-javascript-docker2
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- checkout: common
```

Pipeline UI

[image]

Rest API Result:

[image]

In this case, you can use Rest API to get the Build definition Id and the latest build id. Then you can use the Build definition id and the latest build ID in the Runs - Get Rest API.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/{BuildDefinitionID}/runs/{Latestbuildid}?api-version=7.1-preview.1
```

**Update:**

Powershell script sample:

```
$token = "PAT"

$url="https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/{definitionid}/runs?api-version=7.1-preview.1"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get  -ContentType application/json

foreach($pipelineid in $response.value.id)
{
 echo $pipelineid
 $urlgetinfo ="https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/{definitionid}/runs/$($pipelineid)?api-version=7.1-preview.1"

 $response1 = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $urlgetinfo -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get  -ContentType application/json

 echo $response1.resources.repositories.common.refName
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Looks promising - however, when I try this, `resources` always comes back as `null` when calling the [Runs - List API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1).

Comment: Yes. The run list rest api will not return the resources info. We need to use the Rest API: Run-Get:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1  We can use scripts to combine the two APIs run list and run get. Run list to get all IDs, pass to run get to get details

Comment: @F-H I have shared a PowerShell script sample about the question. You can refer to it

Comment: Thank you, it works similarly in my code. It feels a bit inefficient to first fetch all the (according to the docs, up to 10000) recent runs just to get the IDs, and then to query all runs again to get the details. But if that's what the API currently offers, I'll go with it.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the shared screenshot and the description that

> The underlying pipeline is executed for different branches in my source repository;
>
> The second one is the one I'm actually interested in; it indicates which release branch the build was executed from.

It seems that you have defined the repository resources in this pipeline, but there could be some misunderstandings of its usage.

You haven't shared your definition of the underlying YAML pipeline that published artifacts and we cannot tell how the repository resource from the `release` branch of `Application` repo is defined/checked out or how the artifacts are published. Assuming you used the simple YAML pipeline below,

```
trigger: none
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: app
    type: git
    name: Application
    trigger:
      branches:
        include:
        - release*
steps:
- checkout: self
  path: self
- checkout: app
  path: app
- powershell: |
    tree $(Agent.BuildDirectory)
    Write-Host "The Triggering repo is $(Build.Repository.Name)"
    Write-Host "The Triggering branch is $(Build.SourceBranch)"
    Write-Host "The Triggering branch name is $(Build.SourceBranchName)"
  displayName: Show file structure in Agent.BuildDirectory
- publish: $(Agent.BuildDirectory)/self
  artifact: self
  displayName: Publish artifacts from self
- publish: $(Agent.BuildDirectory)/app
  artifact: $(Build.SourceBranchName)_$(Build.Repository.Name)
  displayName: Publish artifacts from app
```

1. It will be triggered by any commit on `release*` branches from the `Application` repo;
   [image]
2. As soon as the pipeline is triggered, it will checkout the code from both `self` repo and `app` repo into the relative paths under `Agent.BuildDirectory`; the code from the `App` resource repo is dynamically checked out based on the branch that the triggering commit is pushed onto.
   [image]
3. The pipeline then proceed to publish 2 artifacts with alias of `self` and `$(Build.SourceBranchName)_$(Build.Repository.Name)`
   [image]
4. To download the expected artifacts, you can use the API below with selected artifact alias.

   ```
   GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/{pipelineId}/runs/{runId}/artifacts?artifactName={artifactName}&api-version=7.1-preview.1
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your response - I will try to understand whether it is applicable for me; I have no insight into the pipeline that is running, as that is handled and created by a different team. I just need to consume its output. This is perfectly possible with the web-based DevOps UI, so now I'm attempting to automate the same operations in a script.

Comment: Glad to help. I can't agree more that it would be helpful for us to understand the expectation if we know more about how the pipeline generated artifacts outputs. Please feel welcome to test with the current sample and share some more details if further assistance is required.

Comment: By the way, if you would like one **pipeline** to consume the artifacts published by **another pipeline**, you may consider using [pipeline resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#define-a-pipelines-resource). This is simply a wild guess on your workflow, so hope it won't misguide you. Cheers.

Comment: Relying on a pipeline that you can't see the code for, that you don't have at least read-only access to, is an issue and is very counter-productive. I'm assuming this is just one of many organizational issues you need to deal with every day. :)

Comment: Downloading the artifact does not appear to actually be as straightforward as is insinuated in the last step here - I have created a [follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77928206/how-do-i-download-an-artifact-from-the-devops-run-artifacts-rest-api).