# How do I download an artifact from the Pipeline Run Artifacts REST API?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am now able to identify the latest run of a given Azure DevOps pipeline from a specific branch in a specific repository using the DevOps REST API, as described in the answers on [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77754217/how-can-i-distinguish-builds-from-different-branches/77756786).

So, the latest step is retrieving the [`Run` data structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1#run) from the [Pipelines / Runs GET endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1), and thereby the run ID.

It seems I can now query the [Pipelines / Artifacts GET endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1) to retrieve the [`Artifact` data structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1#artifact) that describes my artifact.
For this purpose I am sending the following GET request:

```
https://dev.azure.com/<org>/<project>/_apis/pipelines/<pipeline-ID>/runs/<run-ID>/artifacts?api-version=7.1-preview.1&artifactName=<artifact-name>&$expand=signedContent
```

So far, so good - however, I am not sure about how I can actually download the *content* of the artifact to a local file (or set of files).

The result from the Artifact GET endpoint is an object with only a `name` and a `url` property:

```
name : <artifact-name>
url  : https://dev.azure.com/<org>/<some GUID>/_apis/pipelines/<pipeline-ID>/runs/<run-ID>/artifacts?artifactName=<artifact-name>
```

The `signedContent` field that appears in the documentation is not present (even though I have added the `$expand=signedContent` parameter to the request).

**How can I access the artifact content?**

The `url` field just contains a pointer to the artifact description itself, as described in the documentation ("Self-referential url"), not a pointer to the artifact content.

In case it is related to access rights, on the PAT I am using for API access, the following permissions are granted on READ level:

- Build
- Code
- Packaging
- Release

(But even when I grant full access to the PAT, nothing changes.)

---

One interesting observation is that when I download these artifacts from the web-based DevOps UI, the URL that is being used looks like this:

```
https://dev.azure.com/<org>/_apis/resources/Containers/<integer-number>/<artifact-name>?itemPath=<artifact-name>%2F<path-in-artifact>
```

Thus, there might be a chance of downloading it as a "container". The [`RunResources` data structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1#runresources) (an instance of which can be obtained from the run's `resources` property) does indeed offer a `containers` collection. Unfortunately, unlike the `repositories`, it comes back as NULL from the Run GET endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> however, I am not sure about how I can actually download the content of the artifact to a local file (or set of files).

You can use rest api [Artifacts - Get Artifact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/artifacts/get-artifact?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1) to get the artifact `download url`. then download the artifact as a local file.

The `buildId` is the runid you mentioned in your post.

[image]

Script as below:

```
# Define parameters
$organization = "orgname"
$project = "projectname"
$buildId = "buildid"
$artifactname = "artifactname"
$pat = "PAT" # Personal Access Token

# Create Authorization header
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f "",$pat)))

# Define the API URL to get the latest build artifact
$uri = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/build/builds/$buildId/artifacts?artifactName=$artifactname&api-version=7.1-preview.5"

echo $uri

# Call the API
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Method Get

echo $response | ConvertTo-Json

# Download the artifact
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $response.resource.downloadUrl -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -OutFile "c:\temp\artifact.zip"
```

[image]

Comment: "The `buildId` is the runid you mentioned in your post." - this is the crucial statement in this answer. I was aware of the endpoint you described, but it wasn't clear to me from the documentation that build and run IDs can be used interchangeably (i.e. that the two APIs for dealing with pipeline runs, i.e. the (older?) Builds API and the (more recent?) Pipelines API can indeed be used in conjunction.

Comment: In artifact rest api of build, `buildId` is `The ID of the build`. In artifact rest api for pipeline, `runId` stands for `ID of the run of that pipeline`.  As per your previous link, you are running yaml build pipeline,  `buildid` and `runid` are same thing just different description. What only need to pay attention is to place correct value for different rest api to get target information.

Answer (score 1):

The first step, you can use this URL to obtain the structure of the artifacts root directory.
The values of type are: public/private/release
https://dev.azure.com/$my_org/$type/_apis/build/builds/$build_id/artifacts?api-version=6.0

Return as follows：

```
    {
  "count": 7,
  "value": [
    {
      "id": xxx,
      "name": "metadata",
      "source": "xxxxx",
      "resource": {
        "type": "PipelineArtifact",
        "data": "xxxx",
        "properties": {
          "RootId": "xxxx",
          "artifactsize": "14",
          "HashType": "xxx",
          "DomainId": "0"
        },
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/$my_org/$project_id/_apis/build/builds/$build_id/artifacts?artifactName=$FileorDirName&api-version=6.0",
        "downloadUrl": "https://xxx?format=zip"
      }
    },
    The remaining six directories.
]
```

Then you can use downloadUrl to download all files in the directory.
The download format is zip.
Or you can modify the downloadURL.
For example, if the downloadURL for dir a is:
`https://xxx/content?format=zip` And I want to download `a/b/c.json`
You can modify the downloadURL to:
`https://xxx/content?format=file&subPath=%2Fc.json`
But if the directory depth exceeds 1 level, such as `a/b/c/d.json`
You can modify the downloadURL to:
`https://xxx/content?format=file&subPath=%2Fa%2Fb%2Fc%2Fd.json`
[image]

Comment: Well, where do I get the build ID from? Is it the same as the run ID I obtain from the API endpoints I mentioned, i.e. pipeline runs?

Comment: These are the variables you can use in azure devops:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml  
For buid_id, you can use this one: $(Build.BuildId)

Comment: Those are variables available when running a script inside a pipeline. I'm working on a PowerShell script that is supposed to be run on a local machine to automatically retrieve some data from our DevOps project, so I don't have access to those variables.

Comment: Also, I don't think there is anything I can do recursively there, as you imply. When I query the artifact with an `artifactName` parameter set, I get the artifact as a whole. I am not getting any information on the individual folders within the artifact. That is, I can go from level "0" (all artifacts) to level "1" (just one individual artifact), but not any deeper.

Comment: Sorry, recursion doesn't work, you can try modifying the downloadURL, but this way is very inelegant.
I updated the method of modifying downloadURL to the answer.